# How to handle formatting a regular string which could be a f-string [C0209]

Tags: python, pylint, f-string

For the following line:

```
print("{0: <24}".format("==> core=") + str(my_dict["core"]))
```

I am getting following warning message:

> [consider-using-f-string] Formatting a regular string which could be a f-string [C0209]

Could I reformat it using `f-string`?

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: Gains from f-strings https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1205969258800275456 
Reference from Pylint https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/convention/consider-using-f-string.html#consider-using-f-string-c0209

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the code to `print(f"{'==> core=': <24}{my_dict['core']}")`. The cast to string is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the refactoring would look like this:

```
print(f"{'==> core=': <24}" + str(my_dict['core']))
```

Basically, instead of `"{0:...}".format(bar)` you write `f"{bar:...}"`. (Note, you have to use single quotes inside of your f-string, since double quotes would terminate the string too early.)

Check out https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/ for a nice introduction to f-strings.

Comment: You just added `f` at the beginning. I know `f"{bar:...}"` but how could I get rid of `+` section

Comment: Hi @alper, the answer above shows you how to do that. Note that your warning was not because of the `+`. It was because you were using a regular string and calling `.format` on it.